# How to consume backpress events in web app side in Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, web-applications, webview

Working on `Kotlin` `WebView` with JS interface where my web app requires to detect `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` event from native side to dismiss a web app dialog if presenting. If dialog is dismissed I should do nothing in native side (return true to super), otherwise I need to finish web view activity (return false to super). To just catch my intention please read the below code, I implemented on my custom `WebView` as a clue,

```
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {

    if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> {

                this.evaluateJavascript("onDeviceBackPressed();", ValueCallback {
                    if (it == "1") {
                        // "Web app consumed onDeviceBackPressed event!"
                    } else {
                        // "Web app did not consume onDeviceBackPressed event!"
                        // super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) won't work
                    }
                })

                // I am required to make the return call wait
                // return true/false base on status returned by js func
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}
```

But I know it is not possible to wait super call asynchronously. How do I handle that situation on other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consume KeyEvent during first key down event when waiting for JS then re-use it when you obtain the result.

I used a trick like this for touch events once, so it should work.

```
var delayedKeyCode : Int? = null
var delayedKeyEvent : KeyEvent? = null
var keyDownJSResult : String? = null

override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> {
                // see if there's "result" provided from JS
                keyDownJSResult?.let{
                    keyDownJSResult = null    // wipe out result so it's not triggered twice
                    if (it == "1") {
                        // "Web app consumed onDeviceBackPressed event!"
                        return true
                    } else {
                        // "Web app did not consume onDeviceBackPressed event!"
                        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
                    }
                }
                // otherwise store keyDown arguments for later and trigger JS
                delayedKeyCode = keyCode
                delayedKeyEvent = event
                this.evaluateJavascript("onDeviceBackPressed();", ValueCallback {
                     // when JS returns value, trigger this onKeyDown event again
                     val oldCode = delayedKeyCode
                     val oldEv = delayedKeyEvent
                     delayedKeyCode = null
                     delayedKeyEvent = null
                     keyDownJSResult = it
                     onKeyDown(oldCode, oldEv)
                })
                // always consume event when waiting for JS result
                return true 
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}
```

Comment: Pawel you can see my answer. It can be solved without extra variables.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan it can, but I was writing it of top off my head and as I said I used it for touch event (which is invoked much more often) and I used those variables to prevent extra touch events from firing when they're set. Also I was re-invoking touch event from `@JavaScriptInterface` so variables in-method scope were no good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I a little trick solves my problem,

```
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {

    if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> {
                this.evaluateJavascript("onDeviceBackPressed();", ValueCallback {
                    if (it == "1") {
                        // consumed by web app, do nothing
                    } else {
                        // not consumed by web app, fire explicit back press event
                        mContext.onBackPressed()
                    }
                })
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}
```